# How to add some string between string

Tags: bash, shell

I tried to add some string between strings.
I want to add "themev2" to

```
<SEC_FLOATING_FEATURE_COMMON_CONFIG_CHANGEABLE_UI></SEC_FLOATING_FEATURE_COMMON_CONFIG_CHANGEABLE_UI>
```

so that the result is

```
<SEC_FLOATING_FEATURE_COMMON_CONFIG_CHANGEABLE_UI>themev2</SEC_FLOATING_FEATURE_COMMON_CONFIG_CHANGEABLE_UI>
```

I tried to use

```
lama="<SEC_FLOATING_FEATURE_COMMON_CONFIG_CHANGEABLE_UI></SEC_FLOATING_FEATURE_COMMON_CONFIG_CHANGEABLE_UI>"
baru="<SEC_FLOATING_FEATURE_COMMON_CONFIG_CHANGEABLE_UI>themev2</SEC_FLOATING_FEATURE_COMMON_CONFIG_CHANGEABLE_UI>
sed -i 's/$lama/$baru/g' /system/etc/floating_feature.xml;
```

But it does not work :(

Comment: if you're playing with `xml`, then use `xmlstarlet` which is the right tool for the job

Comment: you will have to use a backslash when using sed with special characters like < and >. So use \< and \> instead of directly putting the angle brackets.

Comment: @LohitGupta That is *completely* wrong.

Comment: @sjsam i want to execute that script in TWRP Recovery at android, supported format is .sh anyclue please?